# Comparing values in two columns to determine whether condition is met or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
  Id,
  QtchainId,
  QtimeLoopId,
  THRESHOLDNUM,
  MIN(THRESHOLDNUM) OVER (PARTITION BY QtchainId) AS leastinqtime_chain
FROM
  your_table_name;
```

Currently above query gives me:

| Id | QtchainId | QtimeLoopId | Thresholdnum | Curr_num |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 8621 | 276 |  |
| 6 | 3 | 2 | 642 | 25 |  |
| 7 | 4 | 1 | 48 | 1 |  |
| 8 | 4 | 2 | 316 | 25 |  |
| 9 | 5 | 1 | 721 | 354 |  |
| 10 | 5 | 2 | 4200 | 0 |  |
| 11 | 5 | 3 | 4975 | 25 |  |
| 12 | 5 | 4 | 63 | 2 |  |
| 13 | 6 | 1 | 721 | 354 |  |
| 14 | 6 | 2 | 4200 | 0 |  |
| 15 | 6 | 3 | 4975 | 25 |  |
| 16 | 6 | 4 | 9529 | 12 |  |

I'm trying to add another column result:

Result is the total of CURR_NUM only from the least THRESHOLDNUM    and above

Expected output:

| Id | QtchainId | QtimeLoopId | Thresholdnum | Curr_num | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 8621 | 276 | 301 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 | 642 | 25 | 301 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 | 48 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 4 | 2 | 316 | 25 | 1 |
| 9 | 5 | 1 | 721 | 354 | 381 |
| 10 | 5 | 2 | 4200 | 0 | 381 |
| 11 | 5 | 3 | 4975 | 25 | 381 |
| 12 | 5 | 4 | 63 | 2 | 381 |
| 13 | 6 | 1 | 721 | 354 | 354 |
| 14 | 6 | 2 | 4200 | 0 | 354 |
| 15 | 6 | 3 | 4975 | 25 | 354 |
| 16 | 6 | 4 | 9529 | 12 | 354 |

So you see:
in QtchainId 3 the least Thresholdnum is 642 so then the result is 25+276=301

in QtchainId 4 the least Thresholdnum is 48 so then the result is 1

in QtchainId 5 the least Thresholdnum is 63 so then the result is 2+25+0+354=381

in QtchainId 6 the least Thresholdnum is 721 so then the result is 354

Is there a simpler way to do this? Can anyone help? I'm using SQL Server 2017

The above query is adding everything in curr_num which is incorrect, also clocking high runtime

```
WITH MinCurrentNumWfrs AS (
  SELECT
    QtchainId,
    MIN(threshold_num) AS leastinqtime_chain
  FROM
    your_table_name
  GROUP BY
    QtchainId
)
SELECT  t1.Id,  t1.QtchainId,  t1.QtimeLoopId,  t1.threshold_num,  t1.Curr_num,  t2.leastinqtime_chain,  SUM(t3.Curr_num) AS wafercount
FROM  your_table_name t1
JOIN
  MinCurrentNumWfrs t2 ON t1.QtchainId = t2.QtchainId
LEFT JOIN
  your_table_name t3 ON t1.QtchainId = t3.QtchainId
                    AND t3.threshold_num >= t2.leastinqtime_chain
GROUP BY
  t1.Id, t1.QtchainId, t1.QtimeLoopId, t1.threshold_num, t1.Curr_num, t2.leastinqt_chain;
```

Example :

| Id | QtchainId | QtimeLoopId | Thresholdnum | Curr_num | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 6 | 1 | 721 | 354 | 354 |
| 14 | 6 | 2 | 4200 | 0 | 354 |
| 15 | 6 | 3 | 4975 | 25 | 354 |
| 16 | 6 | 4 | 9529 | 12 | 354 |

Example 2:

| Id | QtchainId | QtimeLoopId | Thresholdnum | Curr_num | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 6 | 1 | 721 | 354 | 379 |
| 14 | 6 | 2 | 4200 | 0 | 379 |
| 15 | 6 | 3 | 531 | 25 | 379 |
| 16 | 6 | 4 | 9529 | 12 | 379 |

Now the value in thresholdnum 531 belonging to qtimeloopid 3 is the least. So we add curr_num of loopid3, 2,1 to get the result (25+0+354=379)

Comment: Please do not spam tag rdbms - tag the single rdbms of interest.

Comment: Sample data prior to your query would be useful.

Comment: Removed other rdbms tag. OP is using `SQL Server 2017` as stated in question.

Comment: @sabreen please take note of the edits that have been made to this question for your next question.

Comment: `in QtchainId 4 the least Thresholdnum is 48 so then the result is 1` What is the rule here?

Comment: Hi @Squirrel,  in QtchainId 4 the least Thresholdnum is 48 so then the result is 1. this is because the result is only supposed to add starting from the llopid of the least and above. In this case the least 48 belongs to loop id 1 which is already the highest so no need to add

Comment: What's the purpose here? SQL is made to store and retrieve data in/from a database and  to run some basic logic.. This use case should better be done by the application/report or whatever you use rather than in pure SQL.

Comment: I'm trying to create this for my report for analytics purpose. So i need to first get these values for analysis.

Comment: What kind of report, what tools/programing language do you use? I don't see why that should be done in SQL. I guess this would be a far too complex and too slow query. A tool that can execute SQL queries and do something with the results, should also be able to do further logic on the result set. If not, it would be better to change the tool than doing things in SQL that shouldn't be done there.

Comment: My tool for the report is Microsoft report builder. And my backed data that I work with is in SQL. So I'm trying to add these values, have provided additional example just edited for more clarity

Comment: apart from the high runtime, the result itself is incorrect since result should be get the least thresholdnum and then we add curr_num of loopid(belonging to the least thresholdnum) and the values of the loop id's above to get the result . Anyone know how to get this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [FIRST_VALUE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get the `QtimeLoopId` with the lowest `THRESHOLDNUM` value. Then case expression to conditionally sum the `Curr_num`

```
SELECT
  Id,
  QtchainId,
  QtimeLoopId,
  THRESHOLDNUM,
  Curr_num,
  Result = SUM(CASE WHEN QtimeLoopId <= LoopID THEN Curr_num ELSE 0 END) 
               OVER (PARTITION BY QtchainId)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    Id,
    QtchainId,
    QtimeLoopId,
    THRESHOLDNUM,
    Curr_num,
    LoopID = FIRST_VALUE (QtimeLoopId) over (PARTITION BY QtchainId 
                                                 ORDER BY THRESHOLDNUM)
  FROM
    your_table_name
) D;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. This works ! :D